# How to zoom in and Zoom out bitmap in android canvas from multiple bitmap?

Tags: java, android, canvas, bitmap

I have created `bitmap` on android canvas and I want zoom-in and zoom-out I am storing images on `Arraylist` . It's zooming correctly but when there is multiple `bitmap` all the `bitmap` zoom-in and zoom-out. I want to Zoom only Specific `bitmap` which I touch. In My code there is Functionality to drag image it work completely but when `bitmap` zoomed its or working.

Here is  code

```
public class ZoomView extends View {

images touchedCircle;



private ScaleGestureDetector scaleDetector;
private float scaleFactor = 1.f;


private BitmapDrawable bitmap;


private HashSet<images> img = new HashSet<images>(CIRCLES_LIMIT);
private SparseArray<images> mCirclePointer = new SparseArray<images>(CIRCLES_LIMIT)


public ZoomView(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public ZoomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    mPaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(5);
    mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);

    bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.deleteforever);


    bitmap = (BitmapDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mesej);
    scaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());

}

 @Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    for (images img1 : img) {

        canvas.save();
        canvas.scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap.getBitmap(), img1.centerX, img1.centerY, null);
        canvas.restore();
    }
}

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(final MotionEvent event) {
    boolean handled = false;

    scaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    images touchedCircle;

    switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

          xTouch = event.getX(0);
          yTouch = event.getY(0);

          touchedCircle = obtainTouchedCircle(xTouch, yTouch);
          touchedCircle.centerX = xTouch;
          touchedCircle.centerY = yTouch;
          touchedtext = obtainTouchedText(xTouch2, yTouch2);
          mCirclePointer.put(event.getPointerId(0), touchedCircle);



            invalidate();
            handled = true;
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

        touchedCircle = mCirclePointer.get(pointerId);

                if (!scaleDetector.isInProgress()){
                    if (null != touchedCircle) {

                        touchedCircle.centerX = xTouch - bitmap.getBitmap().getWidth() / 2;
                        touchedCircle.centerY = yTouch - bitmap.getBitmap().getHeight() / 2;
                        invalidate();
                    }
                }


            invalidate();
            handled = true;
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

        invalidate();
         handled = true;
         break;


        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:

            mCirclePointer.remove(pointerId);
            invalidate();
            handled = true;
            break; 


        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            zooming=false;
            invalidate();
            handled = true;
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
    invalidate();
    return super.onTouchEvent(event) || handled;

    }

     private static class images {
    int radius;
    float centerX;
    float centerY;

    images(float X, float Y) {
        this.centerX = X;
        this.centerY = Y;
        this.radius = radius;
    }



private images obtainTouchedCircle(final float xTouch, final float yTouch) {
    images touchedCircle = getTouchedCircle(xTouch, yTouch);

    if (null == touchedCircle) {
        touchedCircle = new images(xTouch, yTouch);

        if (img.size() == CIRCLES_LIMIT) {
            img.clear();
        }

        if (c.getImage() == 1) {
            img.add(touchedCircle);
        }
    }

    return touchedCircle;
}


private images getTouchedCircle(final float xTouch, final float yTouch) {
    images touched = null;

    for (images circle : img) {

        if ((circle.centerX < xTouch) && (circle.centerY < yTouch)) {

            float bitmap_width =bitmap.getBitmap().getWidth();
            float bitmap_height = bitmap.getBitmap().getHeight();

            float width = circle.centerX + bitmap_width;
            float height = circle.centerY + bitmap_height;


            if ((xTouch < circle.centerX + bitmap.getBitmap().getWidth()) && (yTouch < circle.centerY + bitmap.getBitmap().getHeight())) {

                touched = circle;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return touched;
}


private class ScaleListener extends
        ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        scaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();
        scaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(scaleFactor, 3.0f));
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}
```

}

Thanks for Help in Advance...

Answer (score 1):

You're using a single scale factor for all images.  You'd need to keep an array of scale factors, one for each image.  Then in your onDraw when you scale, select the correct scale factor for that image.